# How to find what version of phpunit introduced particular methods

Tags: php, phpunit

I was running phpunit 3.7.28 (latest version my Ubuntu install could get via apt-get) but it didn't have the `assertNotFalse()` method. phpunit 4.4.0, however, does seem to have it.

On php.net if you look up a function you can see the version of PHP in which it was introduced. Can you do the same with phpunit?

Comment: I don't see any documented `assertNotFalse()` method (which is kinda like `assertTrue()`, no?) https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html

Comment: The only place you'll find that information is in the changelogs https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki - the phpunit website allows you to easily switched between stable and alpha/beta release documentation, but that's still too new for you.

Really, I'd skip what's in your Ubuntu package and just install it via composer to get the latest and greatest version.

Comment: Oh interesting - may docs are still missing from released versions https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-documentation/issues/172

Comment: @MIchael Berkowski - search for "assertNotFalse() is the inverse of this assertion and takes the same arguments.". Also, `assertTrue()` does `=== true` - not `== true`. As proof do `$this->assertTrue(1)`. `!== false` and `=== false` are not the same thing. `1 !== false` is true but `1 === true` is false.

Comment: @neubert Yep I found it -- I was looking for it in the left column anchors, which it apparently the "Not" inversions of assertions do not appear.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on which php version you have,
in your apt sources you need to specify the php version and do a php upgrade.
then you'll need to remove and install phpunit again to get the latest php unit.

you can use `ppa:ondrej/php5`

It's now on 5.5 and also includes Apache 2.4 update.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

If you don't have add-apt-repository binary do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

you sure you update before you do any of this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Option 2:**
*get rid of the old phpunit*

you can install it with `.phar`

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar

curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
chmod +x *.phar
```

then do a

```
phpunit --version
```

you should get

```
PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```